# Extra Characters in python Argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argparse function:

```
def argParse():
# Possible Arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("-s", "--search", dest="s", help="Seach parameters")
parser.add_argument("-d", "--directory", dest="d", help="Choose Directory to save data")
args = parser.parse_args()

params = str(args.s)
directory = str(args.d)
if params == "None":
    print("Search parameters are null, exiting program.")
    parser.print_help()
    exit(1)
if directory == "None":
    print("directory is null, storing to current working directory.")
```

But, it is adding a extra capitol S and D to the useage output? Any idea on how to clean this up?

```
usage: scan.py [-h] [-s S] [-d D]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -s S, --search S     Seach parameters
  -d D, --directory D  Choose Directory to save data
```

Comment: yes, that's a placeholder for what you should enter _after_ the `-xxx` switch.

Comment: @COLDSPEED how do I get rid of that?

Comment: Why would you want to? Do you want to make it harder for users to understand what the input to your program should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `metavar` kwarg.

try this:

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', dest='s', metavar='\b', help='Search parameters')
    args = parser.parse_args()

parse_args()
```

`\b` is the backspace character, so it also removes the space between the two,
as opposed to using `""` which I beleive would still leave a space after the initial variable name.

> output of `python argparse_test.py -h`:

```
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [-s]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -s, --search  Search parameters
```

Comment: Thanks @ Jebby, I appreciate it!